# State in child component is not getting updated after button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I was trying to create a delete operation on the array of objects (videoData).videoData is getting mapped in the child component along with the DELETE button. At the click of the DELETE button in the child component (childComp).

I want to set the current id to the "childData" state in the child component but it's not getting updated with the current id.

When I am consoling log the childData, in the child component, it still says null which means it was not updated.Why is it not updating?

My own explanation -
When the delete button is getting clicked, the testFunc() is getting fired in the parent component which is removing the item with that particular id from videoData array, and as a result, the id is not able to pass to the child component due to which child component is getting rendered with the original state (null). I don't know if the explanation is correct or not, can someone help me in clearing this up?

```
function ParentComp() {
  const [videoData, setvideoData] = useState([{ id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]);
  function testFunc(id) {
    let hasMatch = false
    if (!hasMatch) {
      let arr = videoData.filter(item => {
        return item.id !== id
      })
      setvideoData(arr)
    }
  }
  return (
    <childComp testFunc={testFunc} videoData={videoData}/>
  )
}
```

```
function childComp({testFunc, videoData}) {
  const [childData, setchildData] = useState(null)
  function ChildFunc(itemId) {
    testFunc(itemId)
    setchildData(itemId)
  } 
  console.log(childData)  //null (state not getting updated)
  return (
    <>
    {videoData.map((item) => {
      return (
        <button onClick={() => ChildFunc(item.id)}>Delete</button>
      );
    })}
  </>
  )
}
```

Comment: working as expected for me [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-hugle-xim9in?file=/src/App.js) (Name your components with capital letters to avoid problems later)

Comment: Same here, childData is null before actually clicking the button. Once you click it, it console logs the correct number.

Comment: why it is not working in my local environment, in my local environment, its just printing null, if the state in parent and child is updating simultaneously, in that case, the parent will rerender, and then the child will rerender, won't the state in the child will reset in that case?

Comment: State is not reset on rerender (as that would defeat the purpose). The item with the stored id no longer exists but it is still held in the child state. (this is actually a case where you shouldn't have a child state since it is derivative of the parent state...)

Comment: so can you suggest me something now on how should i proceed, whenever I am asking about the issue to someone else, then everything works fine in codesandbox, but it's not working as expected in my VS code, how should I address the issue?

Comment: It seems it may be something outside of the code you've shown or a configuration/import error in your project, there is no way for us to help with what we can't see.